# mysql_secure_Installation is missing in my mysql installation

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm following [this guide](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/setting-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2-in-5-minutes/) with my new Linux AMI on EC2.

After installing mysql:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

And running it:

```
service mysqld start
```

I tried running:

```
mysql_secure_Installation
```

But got:

mysql_secure_Installation: command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: mmm... how embarrassing...

Comment: Tell me about it. I did mysql-secure-installation and wasted like half hour why the command wasn't working.